# What happened after entered " flask run" on a terminal under the project directory?

Tags: python, flask

What happened after entered "flask run" on a terminal under the project directory?
How the python interpreter gets the file of flask.__main__.py and starts running project's code?

I know how Flask locates app. What I want to figure out is how command line instruction "flask run" get the flask/__main__.py bootup

Comment: You can look at [the code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/c5c8bbc7f699de6b81ebd9893dc0a2289ae688dc/flask/cli.py#L364) yourself to see the logic how Flask locates app.

Comment: I know how Flask locates app. What I want to figure out is how command line instruction "flask run" get the flask/__main__.py launch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask` is a Python script. Since you stated you are not a beginner, you should simply open the file (/usr/bin/flask) in your favorite text editor and start from there. There is no magic under the hood.

Comment: Thanks! I find the code. it's start from the "main" function from flask.cli module

Answer (score 0):

To run the application you can either use the flask command or python’s -m switch with Flask. Before you can do that you need to tell your terminal the application to work with by exporting the FLASK_APP environment variable:

Imp - **This launches a very simple builtin server**.

Please read it :- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Comment: I'm not a beginner. I want to know the underlying mechanisms.